# Multiple sum columns in single select query and group by id

Tags: sql

```
PatientId   PatientName CashAmount  CreditAmount    CreditCardAmount
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1           AMALRAJ A        0               0            0
1           AMALRAJ A        0             100            0
1           AMALRAJ A        0            1500            0
1           AMALRAJ A     1459               0            0
```

I need result like this:

```
PatientId   PatientName   CashAmount    CreditAmount    CreditCardAmount
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           AMALRAJ A        1459           1600                0
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    PatientId,
    PatientName,
    SUM(CashAmount) AS CashAmount,
    SUM(CreditAmount) AS CreditAmount,
    SUM(CreditCardAmount) AS CreditCardAmount
FROM table_with_patients
GROUP BY PatientId, PatientName
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way is without `group by` cluase :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       PatientId,
       PatientName,
       SUM(CashAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY PatientId,
                                         PatientName) CashAmount,
       SUM(CreditAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY PatientId,
                                           PatientName) CreditAmount,
       SUM(CreditCardAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY PatientId,
                                               PatientName) CreditCardAmount
FROM table;
```

Result :

```
PatientId   PatientName CashAmount  CreditAmount    CreditCardAmount
1            AMALRAJ A  1459        1600             0
```